# Transforming structures into logic

Tags: predicate-logic

Does anyone have any good examples or know where I could find examples of transforming simple structures from graph theory into predicate logic?

Comment: what do mean with "transforming"?

Comment: encoding e.g if you were talking about points and lines,  in logical terms it would be something like {p^1, L^1 , lO^2} where p is a point, L a line and Lo meaning lies on

Comment: Yes. If $R$ is a binary relation symbol of your logical language, you can interpret the formula $xRy$ as: the nodes $x$ and $y$ of a given graph are connected via an edge of the graph. In order to fully understand how formal logic can be used to formalize statements about mathematical objects like graphs, you should study an introductory textbook about mathematical logic.

Comment: ok, are there any examples of this sort of thing out there?  I just need to practise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *graphs*, you can see :

- Jouko Vaananen, [Models and Games](https://books.google.it/books?id=uDDDbkfZpIEC&pg=PA35) (2011), **Ch.4 Graphs**, page 35-on.

Comment: exceptionally good find. Thanks for your help.